# python string including double quote character

Tags: python, string, double-quotes

I have input strings that are comprised of characters, including double and single quotes " and '

```
B@SS$*JU(PQ
AD&^%$^@!$
%()%@@DDSFD"*")(#
ABD*E@(%J^&@
```

however, when I open the above input from a text file and just print it, the double quotes " in the third line get printed as \xe2\x80\x9d

I am aiming to do a simple character count:

```
B 2
@ 3
S 2
$ 3
etc.
```

so I want to be able to output

```
" 3
```

in the above list. Should I replace the double quotes with something so I can count them and print out the count?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> \xe2\x80\x9d

Is a unicode value for "special" double quotes. You could decode from UTF-8 into Unicode to convert this into a "single" Unicode character.

```
>>> print "\xe2\x80\x9d".decode("utf-8")
”
>>> len("\xe2\x80\x9d".decode("utf-8"))
1
```

If you are using Python 3:

```
>>> print(b"\xe2\x80\x9d".decode('utf8'))
”
>>> len(b"\xe2\x80\x9d".decode("utf-8"))
1
```

So for your file that you are counting (in Python 2):

```
from collections import defaultdict
with open("filename", 'r') as f:
    for text in f:
        decoded = text.decode("utf-8")
        count = defaultdict(int)
        for i in decoded:
            count[i] += 1
```

Comment: thanks a lot, Martin - this definitely helps. Now when I decode each line to utf8, then do a character count, the double quotes appear as u'\u201d'
and again they won't print. Is there a way around that?

Comment: How are you printing it? Also, are you using Python2 or Python3?

Comment: I'm using python 2.76 and I'm creating a dictionary of key-value pairs for the characters counts and then printing the keys. So the double quote gets stored as   u'\u201d': 3, and when I try to print the keys it throws the error:

UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\u201d' in position 0: ordinal not in range(128)

Comment: Are you using `str` function somewhere by any chance? What does your `print` code look like?

Comment: you're a genius - I must have put the str(key) in there at some point when I was playing around. Thank you so much!!!