# How to fix or remove malformed utf-8 characters in Python3

Tags: python, unicode, utf-8

I have several text files that contain characters which python 3 is having trouble handling. The most troublesome seems to be "closing" quotation marks.

I have tried reading the files with:

```
with open(filename, 'r', errors='backslashreplace') as file:
    text = file.read()
with open(filename, 'w', errors='backslashreplace') as file:
    file.write(text)
```

and when opening the file in Notepad++ to view the characters, I get `xE2 x80` highlighted to indicate a non-text character, followed by `\x9d` in normal text.

I see that [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24235797/python-string-including-double-quote-character) deals with the `\xE2\x80\x9D` character. In the python REPL I am able to manually create a bytes object like this, decode it as utf-8, and when printed it appears as the character that I expect. I am not sure why when reading the file the character is not understood correctly.

When reading the file to `ignore` errors, rather than `backslashreplace`, I still get the `xE2 X80` characters appearing, and I have not figured out how to perform string operations to remove them.

Ultimately, my goal is to replace all of these strange quotes with normal quotes. There are several ways I can imagine accomplishing this, but they all require me to somehow address (or remove) the `xE2 X80` character, or to correctly read the 3-byte `\xE2\x80\x9D` character.

Comment: have you tried `.open(filename, 'r', encoding='utf8')`?

Comment: wow, I thought utf8 was used by default, but apparently adding encoding utf8 both on read and write solves the issue! If you'd like to add that as an answer, I'll gladly mark it correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Specifying the encoding type should fix the issue. You can do so by doing,

```
with open(filename, 'r', encoding='utf8', errors='backslashreplace' ) as file:
    text = file.read()
with open(filename, 'w', encoding='utf8', errors='backslashreplace') as file:
    file.write(text)
```

Answer (score 0):

To create a copy of the file omitting erroneous characters:

```
def sanitize_file(original_filename, sanitized_filename):
    with open(original_filename, 'r', encoding='utf8', errors='ignore') as original_file:
        with open(sanitized_filename, 'w', encoding='utf8') as sanitized_file:
            sanitized_file.write(original_file.read())

sanitize_file(filename, 'sanitized_' + filename)
```

Comment: Please add some explanation to the code.